# Receiving ValueError: invalid recstyle object

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, valueerror

I am following the instructions of a pygame project on youtube, [this is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGf2GcyHPhc), I am on the project called "Snake", and in the description of the video, you can find what time it starts and the actual code. I am about 10 minutes into the video. I will show you the code that I have written so far:

```
# Snake project on python

import math
import random
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class cube(object):
    rows = 0
    w = 0
    def __init__(self, start,dirnx=1, dirny=0, colour=(255,0,0)):
        pass

    def move(self, dirnx, dirny):
        pass

    def draw(self, surface, eyes=False):
        pass

class snake(object):
    def __init__(self, color, pos):
        pass

    def move(self):
        pass

    def reset(self, pas):
        pass

    def addCube(self):
        pass

    def draw(self, surface):
        pass

def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows

    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,0), (x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (0,y), (w,y))

def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width
    surface.fill(0,0,0)
    drawGrid(width, rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()

def randomSnack(rows, items):
    pass

def message_box(subject, content):
    pass

def main():
    global width, rows
    width = 500
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    s = snake((255, 0, 0), (10, 10))
    flag = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        redrawWindow(win)


main()
```

When I run the code the tutorial says I should be getting a grid (shown in 55:32 of the video). Instead, I am receiving this message:

```
Windows PowerShell

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\holca\Desktop\Snake> & C:/Users/holca/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/Users/holca/Desktop/Snake/snake.py
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/holca/Desktop/Snake/snake.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/holca/Desktop/Snake/snake.py", line 74, in main
    redrawWindow(win)
  File "c:/Users/holca/Desktop/Snake/snake.py", line 51, in redrawWindow
    surface.fill(0,0,0)
ValueError: invalid rectstyle object
PS C:\Users\holca\Desktop\Snake>
```

I am using VSCode, and I have 2 warning messages talking about some unused variables, but I doubt they have to do anything with the problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the color by a tuple:

<s>`surface.fill(0,0,0)`</s>

```py
surface.fill( (0, 0, 0) )
```

Explanation:

The first argument of [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) is the color (tuple). The other arguments are optional. The 2nd argument is an optional rectangle specifying area to be filled. The 3rd arguments are optional flags.

Hence the instruction `surface.fill(0,0,0)` can be read as:

```py
surface.fill(0, rect=0, special_flags=0)
```

The 2nd argument (`rect=0`) causes the error

> ValueError: invalid rectstyle object

Comment: I understand now thank you so much, my friend! It is running just the way it needs to after the correction.