# screen.fill() command in Python is not working

Tags: python, pygame

I have an issue I would hope someone can help me with today and if you can then please do as I am stuck and articles on here are telling me that what I am being told is wrong should work. I am using PyCharm by IntelliJ and the most recent version of python - 3.8.5 So my goal is to make my PyGame window white as on startup it is black and so when I enter the following code this error appears:

```
import pygame

# Initialise the pygame functions#
pygame.init()

# Create the screen for the user#
root = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load("space.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


# Makes the pygame window appear for longer than a few milliseconds#
runtime = True
while runtime:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runtime = False

    screen.fill(255, 255, 255) #The error appears here and I cant find out why because I have looked at articles and they say this should work#
    pygame.display.update()
```

And the response from PyCharm is:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/doesnotcompute10/OneDrive/Main Doccuments/Personal/Code/Code.PythonPycharm/PyGame/Learning/Space Invaders.py", line 25, in <module>
    screen.fill(255, 255, 255)
NameError: name 'screen' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If anyone knows how to solve please reply and/or email me at doesnotcompute10@outlook.com

**Code on!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues. The name of your display [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is `root` rather than `screen`. Further the 1st argument to [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) is a color (See [Receiving ValueError: invalid recstyle object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003341/receiving-valueerror-invalid-recstyle-object/63003436#63003436)). Thus you have to pass a tuple with 3 components rather than 3 arguments:

<s>`screen.fill(255, 255, 255)`</s>

```py
root.fill((255, 255, 255))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realised too and the tutorial video i was watching was making the whole thing too slow and so I skipped ahead and that was my problem. thanks!